# Multiple Monitors in Remote Session

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Following Situation:

On my desktop computer, I have attached 4 monitors (works great, as it should). If I start a remote session (Microsoft RDP or HP RGS) to another desktop computer with an onboard graphics card and no monitor attached, I only get 1 screen. How can I use all 4 monitors in a remote session?

`mstsc /span` is not an option because if I maximize a window it will blow off to all 4 screens.

Comment: What happens if you check "use all displays for remote connection" in the "Display" tab of the remotedesktop GUI?

Comment: It still appears only on 1 screen

Comment: Check the `/multimon` switch for mstsc

Comment: Isnt rdp multy monitor only supported on enterprise / ultimate editions?

Comment: What version of Windows is on the computer you are connecting to? AFAIK, the "Use all displays" checkbox only works on newer versions, in which case your only option is the `/span` flag.